# What is the proper data annotation to create a composite key in EF6?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 and Entity Framework v6. In this project, I'm also using ASP.NET Identities, a table is created in SQL Server named `dbo.AspNetUserRoles`. This table allows multiple user-role records with the same `UserId`. In SSMS the following is displayed showing the columns and keys:

[image]

I am trying to create a similar table in ASP.NET MVC using EF 6. This is the current class:

```
Public Class SqlDomainUserRole
    <Key>
    <Column(Order:=10)>
    Public Property SqlUserId As String
    <Key>
    <Column(Order:=20)>
    Public Property SqlRoleId As String

    Friend Function ToDomainUserRole() As DomainUserRole
    End Function

    Friend Function ToSqlDomainUserRole(DomainUserRole As DomainUserRole) As SqlDomainUserRole
    End Function

End Class
```

In SSMS it is displayed as follows, missing the additional keys that `dbo.AspNetUserRoles` has:

[image]

I can't add multiple records with the same `SqlUserID`. I assume it is because I haven't setup the Data Annotations correctly to create the proper key structure in SQL Server; or maybe some other fundamental concept I'm missing.

If it is a Data Annotation issue, I can't seem to find the location in EF documentation that explains how to create the composite key I need that combines both `SqlUserID` and `SqlRoleID` in my class above.

What are the proper Data Annotations so that my new table will operate like the `dbo.AspNetUserRoles` table?

Comment: Your second screenshot shows all the same primary key information as the first. It's the foreign key information that is missing. Do some research on how to create foreign keys in EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1st comment by `jmcilhinney` pointed to the right path.  To solve the problem the following classes were defined, although see notes at the bottom, because these class definitions had to wait for the previously coded class to be deleted:

```
Public Class SqlDomainRole
    <Key>
    Public Property SqlDomainRoleID As String

    <ForeignKey("SqlDomainUsers")>
    Public Property SqlDomainUsers As List(Of SqlDomainUser)
End Class

Public Class SqlDomainUser
    <Key>
    Public Property SqlDomainUserId As String

    <ForeignKey("SqlDomainRoles")>
    Public Property SqlDomainRoles As New List(Of SqlDomainRole)
End Class
```

EF then produced the following migration code which creates the table that had been previously defined in code as noted in the initial question:

```
    Public Overrides Sub Up()
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.SqlDomainUserSqlDomainRoles",
            Function(c) New With
                {
                    .SqlDomainUser_SqlUserId = c.String(nullable := False, maxLength := 128),
                    .SqlDomainRole_SqlRoleID = c.String(nullable := False, maxLength := 128)
                }) _
            .PrimaryKey(Function(t) New With { t.SqlDomainUser_SqlUserId, t.SqlDomainRole_SqlRoleID }) _
            .ForeignKey("dbo.SqlDomainUsers", Function(t) t.SqlDomainUser_SqlUserId, cascadeDelete := True) _
            .ForeignKey("dbo.SqlDomainRoles", Function(t) t.SqlDomainRole_SqlRoleID, cascadeDelete := True) _
            .Index(Function(t) t.SqlDomainUser_SqlUserId) _
            .Index(Function(t) t.SqlDomainRole_SqlRoleID)

    End Sub
```

However, it was necessary to first delete the table `SqlDomainUserRole` that had been previously defined in code because duplicate keys were present during the migration update above causing it to fail.  After deleting `SqlDomainUserRole`, then processing a migration with that deletion, the migration shown above was then processed and ran correctly.